# jquery how to access / modify a element in object

Tags: jquery, function, object, constructor

i use a library (hideshare, https://github.com/arnonate/hideshare) to inserts social sharing links in my page.
I build my object, but i have to modify value parameters after creation (so i have to have the access to elements and modify them).

Here is the code of the function:

```
;(function(window, $) {

"use strict";

// HIDESHARE PUBLIC CLASS DEFINITION
// =================================

var Hideshare = function (elem, options) {
  this.elem = elem;
  this.$elem = $(elem);
  this.options = options;
};

Hideshare.prototype = {
defaults: {
  link: document.URL,
  title: document.title,
  description: '',
  media: null
},

init: function() {
  this.config = $.extend({}, this.defaults, this.options);
  this.wrapHideshare();
  return this;
},

wrapHideshare: function() {
  var output = output,
      shareTitle = this.config.title,
      shareLink = this.config.link,
      shareMedia = this.config.media,
      shareDescription = this.config.description;
  }
};

Hideshare.defaults = Hideshare.prototype.defaults;

$.fn.hideshare = function(options) {
  return this.each(function() {
  new Hideshare(this, options).init();
  });
};

window.Hideshare = Hideshare;

})(window, jQuery);
```

To create a new object, it is simple:

```
$(".share").hideshare({
      link: "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/To39sfLShv4/mqdefault.jpg",
      media: "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/h6malT0qlj4/mqdefault.jpg"
  });
```

But when the object is create, how to access and modify the 'media value' for example ?
I must create a variable?

```
var obj = $(".share").hideshare ??
```

thanks

Comment: with other jquery libraries, if I can't modify the element, I just destroy then recreate it. check this to see if it has a destroy method.

Comment: This plugin doesn't have any methods for changing things after it's initialized.

Comment: ok thanks, so i have to create a destroy method like this:  

destroy: function() { ... }